# How can we replace corda specific web server with spring

Tags: corda

As the Corda node webserver, which is a Jetty webserver is being depricated. 
So that how can we develop a Web application specific to a node using spring framework, but the created spring container should be aware of all the CordaApp specific classes developed by user by implementing Corda interfaces like ContractState, Contract, Flow etc.

So my question in one line is How can we replace Corda specific web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example Corda Spring webserver [here](https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/samples).

By including the CorDapp that defines the various states, contracts and flows as a compile dependency for the server, these states are then placed on the classpath and can be referenced by the server's endpoints.

In this case, the CorDapp is defined as another module in the same project, so we use the syntax `cordapp project(":[CORDAPP_NAME]")`. If the CorDapp was defined elsewhere, we would use this syntax instead: `cordapp "[GROUP_NAME]:[CORDAPP_NAME]:[VERSION]"`.

Comment: Hi @joel, So I no need to register any web plugin in the Cordapp, right?

Comment: At least providing a migration guide from 3.3 to 4.x and Spring Boot server would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the above guidelines.Please note ,Spring uses different serialization/Deserialization therefore your response **will vary from the response whatever you are getting using the inbuild cordawebserver.**

For using the corda specific serialization/desrialization ,you need to register **corda's jackson wrapper**  .

example :

```
ObjectMapper mapper =  JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper();
//which is included in this dependency 
cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
```